# Time-series relater error while calculating Sharpe Ratio in R

Tags: r, time-series, finance

am trying to calculate Sharpe Ratio for dataset managers from PredictiveAnalytics package.

It results in an error, although the data format seems to be correct. what can be an issue?

```
'data.frame':   132 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ date       : Date, format: "1996-01-31" "1996-02-29" "1996-03-31" "1996-04-30" ...
 $ HAM1       : num  0.0074 0.0193 0.0155 -0.0091 0.0076 -0.0039 -0.0231 0.0395 0.0147 0.0288 ...
 $ HAM2       : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HAM3       : num  0.0349 0.0351 0.0258 0.0449 0.0353 -0.0303 -0.0337 0.0461 0.0653 0.0395 ...
 $ HAM4       : num  0.0222 0.0195 -0.0098 0.0236 0.0028 -0.0019 -0.0446 0.0351 0.0757 -0.018 ...
 $ HAM5       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HAM6       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ EDHEC LS EQ: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SP500 TR   : num  0.034 0.0093 0.0096 0.0147 0.0258 0.0038 -0.0442 0.0211 0.0563 0.0276 ...
 $ US 10Y TR  : num  0.0038 -0.03532 -0.01057 -0.01739 -0.00543 ...
 $ US 3m TR   : num  0.00456 0.00398 0.00371 0.00428 0.00443 0.00412 0.00454 0.00451 0.0047 0.00428 ...

> SharpeRatio(managers1$HAM3,managers1$`US 3m TR`)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'. 
> SharpeRatio(managers1$`SP500 TR`,managers1$`US 3m TR`)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `xts` series not a `data.frame`. Try something like this:

```
managers2 = as.xts(managers1[,!colnames(managers1)%in%"date"],managers1$date)

SharpeRatio(managers2$HAM3,managers2$US.3m.TR)

SharpeRatio(managers2$SP500.TR,managers2$US.3m.TR)

# > SharpeRatio(managers2$HAM3,managers2$US.3m.TR)
# HAM3
# StdDev Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%): 0.2525301
# VaR Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%):    0.2504936
# ES Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%):     0.2093343
# > SharpeRatio(managers2$SP500.TR,managers2$US.3m.TR)
# SP500.TR
# StdDev Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%): 0.12558293
# VaR Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%):    0.07957460
# ES Sharpe (Rf=0.3%, p=95%):     0.05760917
```